# Как выравнивает vertical-align в inline-block элементах?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Учебный код увидел по фиксированной (статичной верстке). Из него мне не понятно что делает vertical align. Я даже сделал рамку вокруг body , чтобы увидеть как по центру он два элемента ставит при vertical-align:middle; Но ничего не происходит. Или я свойство не понимаю это. Попытался текст какой то внутри написать, но он тоже не выравнивается вне зависимости от значения свойства vertical-align: top , middle или bottom. Что в этом коде делает vertical-align и как понять его работу тут ?

```css
body {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.fixed {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="fixed">Знаешь, каждую ночь я вижу во сне море</div>
<div class="fixed">Знаешь, каждую ночь я слышу во сне песню.</div>
</body>
```

вот как изначально учебный пример выглядел , если надо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если блоки различаются по высоте, тогда смысл есть. А для идентичных нет. Может это осталось от какого-то объяснения или "на всякий случай" при неуверенности в результате.

Comment: Здравствуйте Павел , вот как выглядела в учебном примере https://ibb.co/RQcCXCF html код тотже

Comment: там просто 4 вида верстки, это как он говорит фиксированная, дальше будет , резиновая и адаптивная  https://ibb.co/28y23QC

Comment: Там разница возникает если в одном из блоков сделать другое содержимое, например несколько строк. По умолчанию тогда по одной базовой линии бы становились, а при таком выравнивании по центру становятся. А при одинаковом содержимом смысла нет.

Comment: @Pavel  а я правильно понимаю, что если vertical-align , то текст выравнивается по вертикали или это сам элемент относительно родителя? А вот если родителя нет, то относительно body. Всем родителям родитель)

Comment: Там родитель не при чём. Это выравнивание для строчных и строчно-блочных элементов (не путать с таким же свойством для таблиц). Они по умолчанию выравниваются по базовой линии строки. И когда базовая линия не стыкуется, например у 100px текста и 10px, так можно расположить их на одном уровне по вертикали, то есть 10px текст не будет внизу, а будет посреди большой буквы 100px текста. Это для текста изначально. Ещё например когда в тексте смайлик, он может страшно уезжать куда-то, потому что у него нет базовой текстовой линии. А так всё красиво становится, на одном уровне с текстом.

Comment: А в таких случаях выходит, что используются текстовые свойства для расположения блоков. Что по сути костыль. И к счастью теперь есть флексы и гриды, чтобы поменьше эту ерунду использовать.

Comment: @Pavel  спасибо огромное, несмотря на то , что эта технология устарела и на замену пришли флексы и гриды, Вы поразительно чётко, анатомично грамотно в мельчайших деталях  помните всё это. Я восхищён

Comment: Так это ж всё никуда не делось и не является устаревшим пока. Просто теперь по назначению обычно используется для текста, а не для всего подряд как раньше.